# how to rename a file in neotree without ivy select confusing?

Tags: neotree

I have this directory structure for example:

```
/a/a1.txt
```

I want rename `/a/a1.txt` to `/a/a1`, and hoping this result:

```
/a/a1
```

But when I invoke `C-c C-r` command at the node of `/a/a1.txt` and input character `a1`. Ivy will recommend me `a1.txt`.
After use `enter` key. neotree will give a warning `a1.txt is exist, will you overwrite it?` but I want use `a1` as its new name.

I'm not test if not install `ivy` what will happen, after all, ivy as a tool used every day.

how to rename file `a1.txt` to `a1` in neotree? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ivy` has more than one way of exiting the selection process, not just pressing `enter`.

In particular `ivy-immediate-done` which is bound to `C-M-j` has the following help text

`exit with the current action, calling it on the /current input/ instead of the current candidate. This is useful especially when creating new files or directories - often the input will match an existing file, which you don't want to select.`

As usual there is help available, type `C-h m` at the prompt to discover wonders like `ivy-occur`.